# How Can I implement an transition when change tab in tabview?

Tags: qt, qml

I'm trying to find any way to implement an transition when i navigate between tabs in an TabView in QML, but I can't find that, is there any way to do it ?

my code is:

```
TabView{
    id : tbView
    height: parent.height
    width: parent.width


    Tab{
        HomePage{
            id: home
            height: tbView.height
            width: tbView.width
            onBtnConfigClicked: btnPlay()
        }
    }
    Tab{
        Rectangle{
            anchors.fill: parent
            color: "blue"
        }
    }
}



function btnPlay()
{
    tbView.currentIndex = 1
}
```

the HomePage element has an signal btnConfigClick, then i attach it to the function btnPlay, it function change currentIndex  property to 1,  the first tab is 0, I would like an slide transition when a change the currentIndex.

Comment: You say you're trying to implement then it shows the code you've dealt with.

Comment: @eyllanesc I've modify already my code, I'm new in QML so I don't now if that approach is correct

Comment: In SO we are to learn from our mistakes, we only hope that those who ask will take effort in doing their work, such as the code that I try, the research I should have done, etc.

Comment: I don't hope that anybody do my work, I just want orientation about the steps to follow, if it the correct approach, but I feel that your response is away of help to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can use the `TabBar` compontent together with a `SwipeView`:

From [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-tabbar.html):

```
TabBar {
    id: bar
    width: parent.width
    TabButton {
        text: qsTr("Home")
    }
    TabButton {
        text: qsTr("Discover")
    }
    TabButton {
        text: qsTr("Activity")
    }
}

SwipeView {
    width: parent.width
    currentIndex: bar.currentIndex
    Item {
        id: homeTab
    }
    Item {
        id: discoverTab
    }
    Item {
        id: activityTab
    }
}
```

So changing the `currentIndex` property of `TabBar` will automatically perform a `SwipeView` transition to corresponding item.

Because your question is not entirely clear to me, I do not know whether that is what you wanted to achieve.

Comment: thanks , I appreciate your answer so much, It was very helpful for me. I did not want that the user could interact directly with the transitions, instead it should be do  through play function , so I just assign the `interactive : false` to    ` SwipeView` component and solve, By the other hand ,I will not show the TabBar component all logic will be through buttons. thanks